# How transfer multi parametrs to vuex mutation with respect TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to lunch a mutation but my param is udefine how should I properly transfer my
varrables to make this function works? Pleace help

Component

```
    props:{
      detailGoalIdex:{
        type: Number
      }
    },
    setup(detailGoalIdex) {
    const store = useStore()

    let taskTemplate = {
      title:'',
      description:'',
      quote:'',
    }

    function addTask(){
      store.commit( 'ADD_TASK', {taskTemplate, detailGoalIdex} )
    }//jj. on btn 
}
```

Store

```
ADD_TASK(store, {task, detailGoalIdex}:{task:task, detailGoalIdex:number} ){

  if(store.documents){
     console.log('detailGoalIdex',detailGoalIdex )
     console.log('task',task) //jj. undefine   
//store.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals[detailGoalIdex].tasks.push(task) //jj.this is to achieve
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you commit you set a `taskTemplate` property for the payload. However in the mutation you wait for a `task` property. Yo can try

```
store.commit( 'ADD_TASK', { task: taskTemplate, detailGoalIdex} )
```

instead of

```
store.commit( 'ADD_TASK', {taskTemplate, detailGoalIdex} )
```